# Deleting all but top 10 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have the following SQL statement which seems to be deleting every row in the selected table. What it should be doing is deleting all but the top 10 where the difficulty level equals one.

```
DELETE FROM Scores
WHERE Highscore_ID 
NOT IN (SELECT TOP 10 highScore FROM Scores WHERE difficulty = 1 ORDER BY HighScore DESC)
```

Any suggestions as to why this would be deleting all rows? When running the subquery, it selects the proper rows, however, when deleting, it seems to want to delete every row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You compare Hichscore_Id with a column highScore. Does those columns really have the same values?

Then it should be

```
DELETE FROM Scores 
WHERE Highscore_ID NOT IN
          (SELECT TOP 10 HighScore_ID 
           FROM Scores 
           WHERE difficulty = 1 
           ORDER BY HighScore DESC);
```

EDIT:

Try this

```
DELETE FROM Scores
JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY highscore) AS your_row, * 
      FROM Scores 
      WHERE difficulty = 1 
      ORDER BY HighScore DESC) AS score2 ON score2.HighScore_ID = Scores.HighScore_ID
WHERE Scores.difficulty = 1 AND score2.your_row>10
```

Comment: Wouldn't selecting highscore_ID in the subquery select the top 10 score id's based on the id number rather than the actual high score?

Comment: Well you have to get back Highscore_Id for your subquery but yes, then the order won't fit. You have to add a rank in your table in general and delete all with rank >11), then it would work.

Comment: Thanks. Got it with 

"DELETE FROM Scores
WHERE difficulty = 1 AND Highscore_ID 
NOT IN(SELECT TOP 10 Highscore_ID FROM Scores WHERE difficulty = 1 ORDER BY highScore DESC);"

Comment: You sure it works? Wondering myself if this is MS SQL server then the order by statement get into a syntax error?! order by can only sort columns in the selection.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is a typo or a real error but your select clause should refer to highscore_id, not highscore.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with a as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by name) as ordinal, * from test
)
delete from a where a.ordinal > 10;
```

Related: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/03/possible-in-sql-server-deleting-any-row.html

---

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [beatles]
    ([name] varchar(14));

INSERT INTO [beatles]
    ([name])
VALUES
    ('john'),
    ('paul'),
    ('george'),
    ('ringo'),
    ('pete'),
    ('brian'),
    ('george martin');
```

Query:

```
with a as
(
  select *, row_number() over(order by name) ordinal
  from beatles
)
delete from a
where ordinal > 4;

select * from beatles;
```

Prior deleting:

```
NAME
brian
george
george martin
john
paul
pete
ringo
```

After deleting:

```
NAME
brian
george
george martin
john
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0adcf/6

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be "SELECT TOP 10 highScore FROM Scores WHERE difficulty = 1 ORDER BY HighScore DESC" could be returning null.

My second guess would be "highscore_id" is different from "highscore", so there's no overlap (and nothing's deleted).

*Definitely* double-check your subquery, and make sure it's returning the keys you expect!